# List<byte[]> is getting converted to byte[][] in WCF client proxy

Tags: wcf

I am having below WCF contract:

```
[OperationContract]
List<byte[]> GetDocuments(string key);
```

While consuming this, In client proxy it becomes

```
public byte[][] GetDocuments(string key)
```

Return type List< byte[]> is getting converted to byte[][]. 
Why is this behaviour and How do I get List< byte[]> back as my return type.

Answer (score 1):

WCF serializes your generic List of bytes as a 2 dimension array of bytes. This keeps the information being communicated uncoupled from the .NET framework (which has the implementation for the class List).

While consuming it you can put it back as a List this way:

```
List<byte> myBytes= new List<Byte>(receivedBytes);
```